# Proper way to create android project with c++ support

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm running the latest build of android studio. Trying to make a project compilable and running utilizing the power of this https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi/ c++ stuff. What I've tried so far is create new project with c++ support - it creates the corresponding project structure. It also includes CPP file that is called from the main activity. Now let's say I want all this aforementioned miner code to be there as well - I’ve tried just copy-pasting it into the cpp folder. What are my next steps? Calling ndk-build against `$ProjectFileDir$\app\src\mai`n directory just fails with an error `Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk` . Same goes if I try to import an existing project like https://github.com/mdelling/cpuminer-android - first of all I’m trying to do and ndk-build, but it just fails saying that it treats warning like errors so all the cpp/h functions remain inaccessible and are not packed into resulting apk. If I try to install the resulting apk it just crashed on the start. So for the first case – how can I like all the cpp sources to the app, and for the second – how can I make it work at all?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the crash is probably because your Java code is trying to load the c++ shared library and fails, because the library was not built due to the NDK errors. So take care of the errors first.

Second, did you configure your Android.mk properly? Have a look here, for example (it is for Eclipse and not Android Studio, but the mk file is the same): [Getting started with Android NDK](https://blog.jayway.com/2011/10/13/getting-started-with-android-ndk/). Looking at an existing simple project can also help: [hello-jni](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni).